# How to stop event bubbling in jQuery 1.8?

Tags: jquery, events

I'm having an problem with jquery event bubbling. 
I have a button, which open a message box and have a button which, closes it.
Opening and closing with those 2 buttons is easy.
Problem occurs when I try to close message box with clicking on #overlay div.

Here's my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<button id="open">Open</button>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="message">
        <p>Some error message</p>
        <button id="close">Close</button>    
    </div>
</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background:#ccc;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
}

#overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}

#message {
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-110px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}

#close {
    color:#fff;
    background:red;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:0;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:5px 8px;
}
```

​Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    // cache the body tag
    var body = $('body');

    // open message box
    body.on('click', '#open', function(e){
       $('#overlay, #message').show();         
    });

    // close message box
    body.on('click', '#close, #overlay', function(e){
       $('#overlay, #message').hide();   
       e.stopPropagation();                     
    });            

});​
```

And here is a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vnj6X/

I tried to add

```
// do not close message box
body.on('click', '#message', function(e){
    return false;       
});
```

But in other case I have a login form, and when I click on submit button, it doesn't send the form data to server.

Can anyone help me how to stop event bubling?

I want to close message box div, when I click on #overlay div, but not on #message div.
When I click on #message div, it should not do anything.

Comment: Try using `e.stopPropagation()` rather than `return false`? One only prevents event bubbling, the other prevents event bubbling AND prevents the default behaviour.

Comment: not quite ... obviously those elements are dynamically added ... if you have to use on/delegate, then the bubbling cannot be stopped, because it already happened all the way up to body

Comment: It's not added dynamically, but if it were, how it could be prevented?

Answer (score 3):

Its not event bubling its the nesting. Your message is nested inside the overlay which means any click on the message is also a click on the overlay.

Try this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <button id="open">Open</button>
    <div id="overlay">
    </div>
    <div id="message">
        <p>Some error message</p>
        <button id="close">Close</button>    
    </div>
</div>​
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vq5Nq/

This way when you click the message it doesn't close.

Comment: Ok, but what if I can't change the html code and have access only on js?

Comment: @LadoLomidze Then Jackwanders' answer works. Though normally the overlay is kept outside everything so that it doesn't interfere as per my HTML but hey we all have our own restrictions :)

Answer (score 2):

You could check `e.target.id` to make sure the element clicked is either `#overlay` or `#close`:

```
// close message box
body.on('click', '#close, #overlay', function(e){
    if(e.target.id === 'overlay' || e.target.id === 'close') {
        $('#overlay, #message').hide();
    }            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
// close message box
$('#close').click(function(e){
   $('#overlay, #message').hide();         
});
```

instead of your close message box code.